# Parse.com REST API OPTIONS requests SDK

Tags: rest, parse-platform

For every request I make via REST to Parse.com API, there is an OPTIONS request that gets fired at first. How do I get rid of it? Thoughts? Here is the screenshot of the request: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bdiid997hzwxa72/headers.tiff

Comment: Your browser is doing this, and pretty sure you can't stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get rid of it. It is called [CORS preflight](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests), and it is a browser feature to determine whether a cross origin request from your domain is allowed by the REST API or not.